# Mongoose method returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've successfully defined and used my Items mongoose model as:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Item = new Schema({
  name    : String,
  hierarchy: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: this }],
  hierarchy_size: Number
});
```

On pre and post save I populate the hierarchy_size and hierarchy values accordingly to it's properties making it an hierarchical tree:

```
Item.pre("save", function(next) {
    this['hierarchy_size'] = this.hierarchy.length;
    next();
})

Item.post('save', (doc, next) => {
    if ((doc._id) && (doc.hierarchy.length == 0)) {
        doc.hierarchy = [doc._id];
        doc.save();
    }
    next();
})
```

Now I'm running for each root child (after querying the ones with hierarchy_size == 1), the following method getChildren:

```
Item.methods.getChildren = function() {
    this.model("Item").find({hierarchy: this._id, hierarchy_size: this.hierarchy_size+1}).exec(function(err, children){
        if(!err){
            let childrenHierarchy = [];
            for(let child of children){
                childrenHierarchy.push(child);
            }
            return childrenHierarchy;
        }
    })
};
```

But on the controller, when iterating over first level instances, my call for item.getChildren() returns undefined.

```
app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    Item.find({hierarchy_size: 1}).exec((err, menus) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err.message);
      } else {
        let rootTree = []
        for(let item of items){
          rootTree.push(item.getChildren());
        }
        res.status(200).json(rootTree);
      }
    });
});
```

The item.getChildren method gets called, console.log(this) inside the method shows the correct instance data, childrenHierarchy is populated with the proper children objects, but undefined is returned instead of childrenHierarchy content. Any tips on why it is happening? Am I working properly with the instances returned by the first query?

Comment: Please give it a try, and let me know if something is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!! It was very elucidative

Comment: If you are new to NodeJs you may wish to make a look at that article https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html about `express` error handling, rather than just `res.status(500).json(err.message);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would strongly recommend you to use Promise instead, to avoid callback nightmare.

The answer is most simple: you are working with async function as with plain object, and the second, you didn't return any thing from withing `getChildren` method.

In order to fix you problem just modify your `getChildren` as:

```
Item.methods.getChildren = function() {
    return this.model("Item").find({hierarchy: this._id, hierarchy_size: this.hierarchy_size+1})
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        let childrenHierarchy = [];
            for(let child of children){
                childrenHierarchy.push(child);
            }
            return childrenHierarchy;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("the error occured!", err)
    })
};
```

But, as well you need to modify your API endpoint:

```
app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    Item.find({ hierarchy_size: 1 })
        .exec()
        .then(menus => {
            let rootTree = []
            let promiseChain = Promise.resolve({});

            for (let item of menus) {
                promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => {
                    return item.getChildren()
                    .then(children => {
                        rootTree.push(children);
                    })
                })
            }
            promiseChain.then(() => {
                res.status(200).json(rootTree);
            })  
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json(err.message);
        })   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible as you cannot return from an asynchronous call inside a synchronous method.

what you can do is, you can pass in a callback function for your method, like this:

```
Item.methods.getChildren = function(callback) {
    this.model("Item").find({hierarchy: this._id, hierarchy_size: this.hierarchy_size+1}).exec(function(err, children){
        if(!err){
            let childrenHierarchy = [];
            for(let child of children){
                childrenHierarchy.push(child);
            }
            callback(childrenHierarchy);
        }
    })
};
```

Or you can use promises and make your life easier...